# Angular bloqueando submit de formulário GET

Tags: angularjs

Tenho um formulário onde eu envio uma consulta para a url atual, através de parâmetros `GET`. Por exemplo, eu tenho `url/teste`, ao enviar a consulta por esse formulário, ficará `url/teste?term=minha+consulta`.

Eu não usei `Angular` nessa parte, pois já estava pronta, então o formulário já existia antes.

Quando coloquei o angular, esse formulário parou de fazer o submit.

Exemplificando meu cenário:

```
<body ng-app="my_app">
    <!-- esse input manda para mesma página uma pesquisa GET, por isso não usei "ACTION" -->
    <form id="form-pesquisa">
        <input type="search" name="term" />
        <button type='submit'>Pesquisar</button>
    </form>


    <!-- uso esse formulário no Angular -->
    <form ng-controller="UserCreateController">
        <input type='text' name="email" ng-model="user.email" />
        <input type='password' name="password" ng-model="user.password" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Percebi que o angular está adicionando as classes `ng-submitted` nesse formulário quando eu envio a submissão.

Gostaria de saber como posso usar um formulário, dentro do contexto do `ng-app`, mas podendo fazer uma submissão via `GET`.

O angular realmente bloqueia essas requisições? Como contornar isso?

Comment: O que você quis dizer com "mandar para a mesma página"?

Comment: @CelsomTrindade "através de parâmetros GET" na sequência. Quis dizer que, embora use o AngularJS, quero fazer um envio de formulário comum, via GET, para  a url atual

Comment: E como o segundo formulário é enviado? Engraçado.. pois eu já trabalhei com diversos forms na mesma página mas nunca tive esse tipo de problema..

Comment: @CelsomTrindade o Rapazinho respondeu aí embaixo. Ao colocar o `action` referenciando a própria página, voltou a funcionar corretamente. Eu só acho que a resposta deveria estar um pouco mais completa, explicando porque ocorreu esse comportamento.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade o segundo formulário funciona pelo angular. Mas o primeiro deveria funcionar normalmente, fazendo um submit e enviando um parâmetro `GET` para a url atual.

Comment: Pois é, mas acho que, apesar de ter funcionado, não deve ser o principal motivo desse erro. Você disse que envia pelo Angular, mas como? Através de um button submit? Onde está o button? Pois ele não está dentro do form, talvez seja isso.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade talvez você não tenha entedido: Eu tenho dois formulários. O primeiro é para fazer submit para o PHP (via url com parâmetros `GET`). O segundo, com o angular, mandando os dados via Ajax. O primeiro parou de funcionar depois que comecei a usar o Angular (ou seja, ele não envia  mais a consulta GET). Eu clico no Submit dele, mas ele não faz nada!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43873/discussion-between-wallace-maxters-and-celsomtrindade).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O AngularJS [bloqueia a ação padrão do formulário](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form) a não ser que o `action` seja especificado no `<form>`. Então apenas adicione o `action` referenciando a própria página:

```
<form ng-controller="UserCreateController" action=".">
   ...
</form>
```

Nesse caso, quando você utiliza o `.`, é entendido pelo navegador que você está referenciando a própria página.

Answer (score 2):

Pela resposta do [Vanderlei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/34404/vanderlei-sbaraini-amancio), concluímos que, o problema era a falta do `action` no formulário, onde se desejava fazer uma submissão de dados para o servidor.

Na verdade, é possível você usar o formulário sem o `action` normalmente no `HTML`. Sempre que você fizer isso, o formulário será submetido para a url atual.

Porém, com a falta do `action`, quando você utiliza o Angular, ele bloqueia qualquer submissão. E explico o por quê:

## Mas por que sem o `action` não funcionou, como costuma funcionar sem o AngularJS?

De acordo com a [documentação](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) do AngularJS:

> For this reason, Angular prevents the default action (form submission to the server) unless the element has an action attribute specified

Que traduzindo é:

> Por esta razão, O Angular impede a ação padrão (envio do formulário para o servidor) a menos que o action seja especificado no elemento .

Então, mesmo que a intenção seja utilizar o formulário para enviar uma submissão para própria página, é necessário usar o atributo `action`, pois, por padrão, o angular, na falta desse atributo, utiliza o `preventDefault` para evitar submissões padrão.

Comment: Não entendi o negativo.. A resposta teve uma explicação muito mais bem elaborada e precisa sobre o por que de estar acontecendo o problema ao invés de simplesmente apontar como resolver.

Comment: Na verdade, seria interessante que as pessoas começassem a comentar os  negativos (o site em inglês costuma te pedir, num popup, para deixar um comentário sobre o negativo). É uma pena que, na maioria das vezes, quando você faz isso, você recebe várias retaliações. Eu mesmo não comento mais os negativos que dou, mas nunca daria numa resposta que está explicando um problema ou complementa de forma satisfatória. Talvez alguém tenha feito isso por não ter gostado de eu ter respondido minha pergunta, mas é uma mecanismo do site, e vou usar sempre que puder.

Comment: Eu negativei porque não acho que há necessidade de uma resposta que tem como único propósito complementar uma resposta correta já existente. Essa resposta inteira podia ser transformada num comentário na resposta do Vanderlei e servir o mesmo propósito.

Comment: @Gabe o seu já tá justificado. Com a confusão toda do "edita ou não edita", essa resposta acabou sendo dada e ficou de bobeira. Já que a outra resposta possui os links da documentação. Quando eu respondi, eu só percebi que você não tinha revertido quando fez aquela publicação no meta :p. Sismei com a tal da reversão.